# What is the minimum speed at which the proton has to move for antiproton production?

Tags: special-relativity, particle-physics, kinematics, collision, pair-production

In a collision between 2 protons.
Do each of them have to move at 1c, 0.5c.. ?
The lower the speed, the less likely the production of the antiproton?

Comment: One works with Lorentz invariant quantities for this problem, because what is true at the center of mass can be transformed to any frame by Lorentz transformations.  In this case the energy momentum four vectors, in order to see when there is enough energy in the reaction to produce the particles . speed is not an invariant, http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/vec4.html

Comment: Possible duplicate by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/684905/2451

Comment: Hi Alexander Martin. Welcome to Phys.SE. Please don't repost a question in a new entry. Instead, you are supposed to edit the original question within the original entry.

Comment: @Qmechanic op was advised in a comment that only the minimum could be computed.

Comment: Protons have mass, so they *can't* move at $1c$.